# ListViewItem custom control doesn't respond to clicks in certain empty spaces that are still part of the item

Tags: wpf, xaml, custom-controls

I am trying to make a custom control for that inherits from ListView and one that inherits from ListViewItem. The appearance is fine. The problem is that when clicking on the parts of the control shown below, the item does not get selected - you have to click directly on the image. The text had the same problem with its margins (you could not click in the margins), but I added padding to them. I thought that adding the content inside of `ContentPresenter.Content` would fix the problem, but it didn't.

[image]

Also, if I add this style to my resources, rather than in Generic.xaml, and remove the `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata` method in `NavigationListViewItem.cs`, it does work correctly (not sure what's up there).

The code-behind for the custom controls do not have any addition code added into them. Here is the style in Generic.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ui:NavigationListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ui:NavigationListViewItem}">
                <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <StackPanel x:Name="itemPanel"
                                            MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="19" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition MinHeight="22" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <ui:ColorableImage Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Source="arrow-right-white.png" Height="15" Width="15" />

                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                                        x:Name="itemText"
                                        FontSize="14"
                                        FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                        FontWeight="Bold"
                                        TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Text="Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text "
                                        Padding="3,10,10,10" />
                                </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="itemText" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true"/>
                            <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="false"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Border` background for `NavigationListViewItem` is set to null by default and that won't react to mouse clicks. You need to initialize it to something, for example `Transparent`

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ui:NavigationListViewItem}">
    <!-- other setters -->
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
```

also in your `Trigger` which changes `Background` you don't need to specify `TargetName`. Since you already do `TemplateBinding` you should be to change `Background` directly on the item.

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
    <!-- other setters -->
</Trigger>
```

Comment: It's always something simple...

Also, why does it matter if the background of the border is null or not if the border is there regardless? Whether or not the border has a background doesn't seem like it should determine if the user can click on it or not

Comment: If `Background` brush is not initialized then it's not hit test visible. That's just how it works which in some cases might be useful. If you want your control to be hit test visible in the whole area of the control then you need to initialize `Background` to something.

Comment: Okay, I guess that's just something you have to know. I wonder why Background isn't initialized to Transparent by default. Edit: Actually, nevermind, that makes sense for code-behind purposes to check if it's been initialized or not... Just sort of annoying for XAML purposes

Comment: It is initialized to default value which for `Background`, and other reference types, will be null. It's just not initialized to some instance of a `Brush`. `DependencyProperties` share default value so if it would not be null then all `Control.Background` properties would share reference to same instance of `Brush` and that could be problematic